# How to config networks in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the host, I have created docker network using below command:

```
docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.2.1  \
    -o parent=eth0 pub_net
```

docker network shows below:

```
[root@192-168-2-70 shell]# docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
935ae8b52eb2        bridge              bridge              local
81577f72f606        host                host                local
846d54a2c7da        none                null                local
158428b19c4d        pub_net             macvlan             local
[root@192-168-2-70 shell]#
```

and docker container with specified IP can be started by command:

> docker run --net=pub_net --ip=192.168.2.10 --name hadoop0 --hostname
>   hadoop0 -d -P  hadoop-cluster-hadoop0:v1.1

but when I convert the above command to docker-compose file like below:

```
version: '3'
services:
    hadoop-cluster-hadoop0:
        container_name: hadoop0
        restart: always
        networks:
            pub_net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.2.10
        volumes:
            - /tmp/hadoop0/logs:/tmp
        extra_hosts:
            - "hadoop0:192.168.1.10"
            - "hadoop1:192.168.1.11"
            - "hadoop2:192.168.1.12"
            - "dbus-n1:192.168.2.81"
        image: 'hadoop-cluster-hadoop0:v1.1'
networks:
    put_net:
      external: true
```

the following error occured.

```
[root@192-168-2-70 shell]# docker-compose up -d
WARNING: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: put_net
ERROR: Service "hadoop-cluster-hadoop0" uses an undefined network "pub_net"
[root@192-168-2-70 shell]#
```

Can anybody please help me on how to correct the docker-compose file?
How docker network can be created in docker-compose file, instead created beforehand?

Appreciate your help very much!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look closely, you named your network `put_net` but instead referenced it as `pub_net` in your service definition.

Moreover, when you define the network as `external` it means that it should already be created. If you want docker-compose to do that for you, you can do this instead.

```
networks:
    put_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - 
                  subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
```

If you would like to exactly re-create the network you specified in the question then you would have to downgrade the version from '3' to '2'; This is because some functionality was removed in version '3' and one of these options was the ability to specify `gateway` (at least to the best of my knowledge).

Here is how your docker-compose file would look like. (Notice the change in version from '3' to '2')

```
version: '2'
services:
    hadoop-cluster-hadoop0:
        container_name: hadoop0
        restart: always
        networks:
            put_net:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.2.10
        volumes:
            - /tmp/hadoop0/logs:/tmp
        extra_hosts:
            - "hadoop0:192.168.1.10"
            - "hadoop1:192.168.1.11"
            - "hadoop2:192.168.1.12"
            - "dbus-n1:192.168.2.81"
        image: 'hadoop-cluster-hadoop0:v1.1'
networks:
    put_net:
        driver: macvlan
        driver_opts:
            parent: eth0
        ipam:
            config:
                - 
                  subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
                  gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. my bad..., but according to the docker-compose file you applied, only subnet parameter is provided, how to compose the other parameters of the following command? docker network create -d macvlan \
    --subnet=192.168.2.0/24 \
    --gateway=192.168.2.1  \
    -o parent=eth0 pub_net

Comment: Yes I forgot to add that, my bad. I updated my answer now to include how to re-create this exact network.